# Silverlight Vector US Map

Tags: silverlight, data-visualization

I'm relatively new to silverlight and want to start building a data visualization tool that shows an interactive map of the US and allows me to essentially put a heat map on top along w/ varying points of interest dynamically added.

I'm sure there are commercial tools I could buy that would do all this but I'd like to build it from scratch (or semi-scratch) so I can figure out how to do it on my own.

Can someone maybe point me in the right direction in terms of building the map, putting the heat map up and placing points of interest based on latitude and longitude?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [Bing Maps Silverlight Control](http://connect.microsoft.com/silverlightmapcontrolctp).  I used it [here](http://xmldocs.net/bestbuy) for a demo.

Comment: I want to build the map up myself and do the plotting. I don't want to re-use someone's control